# Cobertura issues in writing ser files

Tags: cobertura

I have implemented Cobertura for the large application in local setup. when i moved same setup to Prod server, I am facing some of the issue and i could not find out the missing part till now. Is there any help from community?

I did implemented Cobertura in following steps.

1. Instrumentation - OK
2. Packaging - OK
3. Modifying in tomact file to add Cobertura.jar n other setup - OK
4. Deployment of Apps - OK
5. Running the apps - Ok
6. Stop the tomcat and seek for updated Cobertura.ser - Its not updating the ser file at all.

i have tried many ways to identify the missing part in step 6 but could not find out. This is large application so finding out the missing area is very hard. can you guys help me out with the verification checkpoint or share your experience with large apps. that would be helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure you read [this faq](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/FAQ#when-i-generate-coverage-reports-why-do-they-always-show-0-coverage-everywhere) that helps you determine if you're doing it right.

Also, I'm not sure about Tomcat, but JBoss has an particular way of shutting down the JVM that interferes with the shutdown hook that Cobertura uses to 'dump' the coverage data to the .ser file. There appears to be a [jboss-only workaround](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/FAQ#im-using-jboss-when-i-stop-the-server-the-coverage-data-file-is-not-written-or-the-coverage-data-file-is-0-bytes-or-cobertura-report-and-cobertura-merge-complain-that-the-coverage-data-file-is-invalid-possibly-throwing-an-eofexception).

Last, another possibility is to explicitly dump the coverage infromation via a [code snippet as show here](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/FAQ#cobertura-only-writes-the-coverage-data-file-when-the-application-server-shuts-down-we-do-not-want-to-stop-our-application-server-after-running-our-tests)